# Errors importing sample Facebook SDK files for Android to Eclipse

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to use Facebook's login API for my Android app, I followed the instructions on the "Facebook for Developers" site at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/ to the latter and when i finished importing the files, i got these errors.

Project FacebookSDK is missing required source folder: 'gen'
Project FriendPickerSample is missing required source folder: 'gen'

and 56 others.
Please how do i resolve this?
I would have posted the image but i need more reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, Click Project->Clean-> Clean All projects. That May help.

Comment: I have done that countless times, i also tried closing and restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Just delete this Facebook sdk archive and download the new from the developers site,import it again ,try not to forget to clean the project !!May be this could help !!

Comment: I am no longer pursuing this objective.Thanks though.